# Are MOK (Machine Owner Key) deleted after OS reinstall or Secure Erase (Data Wipe) on BIOS/UEFI level?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, nvidia, uefi, secure-boot

Some time ago I have installed Ubuntu 22.04 and installed proprietary nvidia drivers on it. That triggered creation of the new MOK (Machine Owner Key). In a meantime I have decided to reinstall the whole system as I wanted to do dual-boot.

So I did the following:

1. Secure Erase (Data Wipe) the SSD via UEFI
2. Reinstall Ubuntu 22.04 in dual-boot

I know that those actions have no impact on Secure Boot Keys (PK, KEK, DB, DBX) as they are stored in the Firmware. However, I am not so sure about MOK and cannot find explicit answer by checking related questions like: [Security boot and mok password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679695/security-boot-and-mok-password) or [What exactly is MOK in Linux for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535434/what-exactly-is-mok-in-linux-for). I only found that MOK are stored in the database of shim (source: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mokutil.1.html).

The Question is: Are MOKs (Machine Owner Key) deleted after OS reinstall or Secure Erase (Data Wipe) on BIOS/UEFI level?

Comment: No, no. UEFI firmware is independent from your storage aside from boot entries.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thx for Your reply! 
Yeah, I got it that UEFI Firmware is independent from storage. However, I am not really sure if MOK are too. Just a second ago I found in ubuntu wiki about UEFI - SecureBoot (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot) that **" the generated MOK key is kept on the filesystem as regular files owned by root with read-only permissions."**. If I get it correctly, that would mean that MOKs are deleted after OS reinstall / SSD erase. Am I right?

Comment: The MOK key as a file belongs to the mass storage. The MOK key is normally imported into UEFI and after that it doesn't matter if the storage is still there.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I have checked that and You were right. By using `mokutil --list-enrolled` I was able to find MOK, which was created on my previous OS installation. Long story short: **MOK (machine owned key) do survive OS reinstall / SSD erase**. Thx for help!