# Replacing Ubuntu with Mint

Tags: linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

I'd like to replace my Ubuntu with Linux Mint on my HP Pavilion 15 (Windows 11 dual-boot).

I created a bootable USB but MOK management does not allow me to proceed. I really don't know what to do, this is the first time I am struggling with MOK. As long as I choose "enroll key from disk" multiple choices appear and I don't know what the result is going to be...

I've been a Linux Mint User for a long time and I think I'd rather continue using it.

Comment: Related - [What exactly is MOK in Linux for?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/535434/100397)